# Has anyone gotten VMWare Workstation 9.0.1 working with vmxwrapper / nvidia optimus?

Tags: vmware, hybrid-graphics

I have an optimus laptop and am desperate to be able to use my discrete GPU with virtual machines.  Recently, a project called vmxwrapper has come out to allow this.  However, I get the following issues:

Using Workstation 9.0.1 / Ubuntu 12.10 (amd64)

Bumblebee fully working, vmxwrapper installed according to instructions.

vmware log:
http://pastebin.com/qbjAeb3A

Relevant information from running:

## LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose optirun vmware -x vmware/Windows\ 7\ x64/Windows\ 7\ x64\ (2).vmx

libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
2012-11-24 14:24:31 6676 no printer configured or none available
2012-11-24 14:24:31 6684 adaptor daemon booted
2012-11-24 14:24:31 6687 connector "vmlocal" booted
2012-11-24 14:24:36 6684 adaptor daemon shut down
2012-11-24 14:24:36 6687 connector "vmlocal" shut down

Mainly, the point is that it's trying to load swrast as opposed to the virtualgl, I think.  Any advice would be great! If anyone has this working, please let me know.